# ActiveX button is appearing on all worksheets

Tags: vba, excel, activex

I'm new to VBA and I'm unable to find answer to this. I have ActiveX Button on one sheet. I'm also creating new sheets is same workbook. Problem is that button is appearing on all of those worksheets. I would like that button to appear only on one worksheet, so it will not be on other worksheets that I create with VBA.

Code in separate module:

```
Option Explicit

Sub copying()

Worksheets(1).Copy After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)

Worksheets(2).Activate

Worksheets(2).Name = "Test"

End Sub
```

Code for button that is calling copying function:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Call copying

End Sub
```

Button is appearing on new worksheet that is created.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you check line 37 in your code? I'd check it for you, but you didn't post it. :( Tough to help debug without seeing the code. :)

Comment: Sorry, added code example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the `Worksheet.Copy` method which copies the sheet and all of its contents including your button. Either use the `Sheets.Add` method(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839847.aspx) or copy the sheet like you already do and delete the button.

`.Add` will just add a new sheet:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
```

`.Copy` will copy the contents of the sheet. If you have a lot of data on the sheet you want copied, it will be easier to copy the sheet and delete the extra button:

```
Option Explicit

Sub copying()
    Worksheets(1).Copy After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    Worksheets(2).Activate
    Worksheets(2).Name = "Test"

    Dim objShape As Shape
    For Each objShape In ActiveSheet.Shapes 
        ' I think 12 is the msoShapeType you need.
        If objShape.Type = 12 Then objShape.Delete
    Next objShape
End Sub
```

Comment: Good solution, but I'd use the constant `msoOLEControlObject` instead of `12`.